# Decompose Expression into Segments

Tags: simplifying-expressions, symbolic, expression-manipulation

Say I have an expression `test = 3 x1^2 - 2 x3^-3` and I would like to decompose the expression into `{3 x1^2, -(2/x3^3)}`, I can do that by using `List @@ test` on Mathematica.

However, the problem I face is that when the expression is `test = x1^2`, i get `{x1, 2}` and for `test = (3 x1^2)` i get `{3, x1^2}` instead of `{x1^2}` and `{3x1^2}` respectively.

The added information I have is the list of variables. For example, if `test = x1^2` I have the list of variables, which is `{x1}`. And for `test = 3 x1^2 - 2 x3^-3`, I have `{x1,x3}`

Is there any other way to get what I want?

Thanks

Comment: You should look at the `FullForm` representation to get an idea of the structure of your expressions if you want to use pattern matching (which can be a minefield for changing expressions).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps what you want:

```
exprs = {3 x1^2 - 2 x3^-3, x1^2, (3 x1^2)};

f[HoldPattern[+z__]] := {z}

f[else_] := {else}

f /@ exprs
```

> ```
> {{3 x1^2, -(2/x3^3)}, {x1^2}, {3 x1^2}}
> ```

Comment: thanks! Referring to your answer, what if the only information I have is `exprs = 3 x1^2 - 2 x3^-3` and I'd wanna obtain `{3 x1^2, -(2/x3^3)}`?

Comment: @arvindrajan92 Perhaps I misunderstand, but that would be produced by `f[exprs]` I believe.  Is that not correct?

Comment: I have gotten what I want and I have added it below as the answer to my question

Comment: In my case, I do not have `x1^2` and `(3 x1^2)` to include in `exprs = {3 x1^2 - 2 x3^-3, x1^2, (3 x1^2)};`. The only detail I have is `3 x1^2 - 2 x3^-3`. Is it possible to get just `{3 x1^2, -(2/x3^3)}`?

Comment: @arvindrajan92 Oh, I see your confusion now.  Sorry!  I just put all your `test` expressions in a list so that it was easy to `Map` my `f` function over them, but the function works independently on each one.  That is, `f[3 x1^2 - 2 x3^-3]` should output `{3 x1^2, -(2/x3^3)}`.

Comment: You mean if I type in `f[HoldPattern[+z__]] := {z}` and `f[3 x1^2 - 2 x3^-3]`, I should be able to get `{3 x1^2, -(2/x3^3)}`? @Mr.Wizard

Comment: @arvindrajan92 Yes, but for the other expressions to yield the output requested you also need `f[else_] := {else}`.

Comment: Thank you very much @Mr.Wizard. That definitely works!!!